# How to insert json string into smarty template?

Tags: javascript, php, smarty3

I prepare json string in php file

```
$groups_json = json_encode($groups);
$smarty->assign('groups', $groups_json);
```

How can I put it properly into  in .tpl file like that

```
<script>
var groups = "{$groups}"; // <-- here
```

I have smarty 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that smarty converted quotes and other stuff to html entities. The answer is to add **nofilter** parameter to the template variable

```
var groups = {$groups nofilter};
```

Comment: Did you think about if that can cause any XSS exploits?